# Defining a list of functions

Tags: functions, functional-style

I'm using polynomial mappings such as

```
s[{x_,y_}] := {x + y^2, y -x}
```

and playing with compositions of such mapping, e.g.

```
s[s[x,y]]
```

My problem is I need to generate a list of these mappings (or an array, or what have you, I'm not sure what's the best data structure in this case) inside a loop, and later to compose them. So I would like to do something like

```
s[[1]][s[[2]][x,y]]
```

the first element in the list of mappings, composed on the second element.
Can someone help me with that ? 
Also, in case there's a better way to define my polynomial mappings, please let me know.

Comment: Your input `s[s[x,y]]` doesn't return output other than `s[{x + y^2, -x + y}]` - is that expected, or did you want `{x + y^2 + (-x + y)^2, -2 x + y - y^2}` as the output?

Comment: `s[{x_, y_}] := (* stuff *)` would be a way to go.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I meant. I'll correct it.

Comment: @Teddy, So I don't really understand - you want to create a list of functions, that is easy enough.  But then what are you doing with these compositions?  Say the functions are `{s1, s2, s3}` - what are you looking to return?  Something like   ` {s1[ s2[ s3[x,y] ] ], s2[ s3[ x,y] ], s3[ x,y] }`?

Comment: @J.M. I'm trying to create approximations for a certain mapping, call it $A[x,y]$, using polynomial mappings. This is done by analysing various parts of $A$, and generating polynomial mappings accordingly. The desired approximation will be the composition of all those polynomial mappings.

Comment: @JasonB Given the list of functions, {s1,s2,s3}, I would like to compose them as you suggest, s1[s2[s3[x,y]]].

Comment: Is this "certain mapping" so complicated that you cannot write about it here? Maybe a different approach is warranted, since this one is apparently making you jump through hoops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also not sure whether I fully understand what you are after. But whenever one is using functions more in a mathematical sense than in a programming one, I think it is worth thinking about using pure functions to represent them. Here is a list of pure functions which each does a polynomial mapping as you describe:

```
polynomials={
  Function[{x, y}, {x + y^2, y - x}],
  Function[{x, y}, {x - y^2, y + x}]
}
```

you can now almost do what you want:

```
polynomials[[1]][x,y]
polynomials[[1]][x,y]
```

only the composition is syntactically somewhat complicated (because you can't use the pattern matcher to unpack/destructure the list arguments for `Function`s, so we have to use `@@` / `Apply`):

```
polynomials[[1]] @@ polynomials[[2]][x, y]
```

but fortunately it is simple enough to provide a helper function which adds some syntactic sugar so handling the entries in the list is less involved:

```
poly[i_Integer][x_, y_] := polynomials[[i]][x, y]
poly[i_Integer][{x_, y_}] := polynomials[[i]][x, y]
```

now you can use the various entries like this:

```
poly[1][x, y]
poly[2][x, y]
```

and composition is also easier:

```
poly[1][poly[2][{x, y}]]
```

And you can also use `Composition`, as suggested in other comments and answers:

```
(Composition @@ {poly[1],poly[2],poly[1]})[x, y]
```

Depending on what the entries in `polynomials` actually are it might make sense to turn that list into an `Association` which then would allow to access the entries by non-integer keys which might make your code more readable and less error prone...